# PHP Session behaves weird wont change value

Tags: php, session, reference

So here is my setup.

In file1 I have a class1. 
In the constructor I create a class variable like

```
$this->session = $_SESSION['test'];
```

In the constructor I set some default values in $this->session like

```
$this->session['something']['somethingelse'] = 'test';
```

Class1 requires (in a function) file2 and initiates class2 (which is inside file2). Calls a function and gives a $this->session. I then referrer to the variable using &$session.

$this->session then changes value in class2 lets say to like

```
$this->session['something']['somethingelse'] = 'test2';
```

When I return to class1 I can see that the values are changed. 
I now call a storeSession function that basically do the reverse of the beginning.

```
$_SESSION['test'] = $this->session;
```

I var_dump both the $this->session and $_SESSION and in file1 I can see the values have been changed.

I then end of by calling another php file where I have

```
session_start();

var_dump(session_id());
var_dump($_SESSION);
exit;
```

But here the result is not right! The value of  $this->session['something']['somethingelse'] is 'test' and not 'test2'! The same goes for for file1 if I reload the page with a var_dump($_SESSION); in the top the value haven't been changed. I debugged the session_id as well and I am definitely running on the same session in all the files!

Now here is some more strange stuff. Its like I cant overwrite the default value I set in the beginning. Something to do with it being a multiple dimensional array?

The last thing I do in my file1 is to change the value. And the first thing I do is var_dump on $_SESSION. The value in the multi-dimensional array wont change(when first set) no matter what I try!

I have even tried vardumping the $this->session value in the end of file1 - confirming it have changed. Unset $_SESSION and then try and set the

```
$this->session['something']['somethingelse'] = 'test';
```

But then it is not set at all! The spot is simply empty. Well the whole $_SESSION is empty. This is the case if I clear session cookies and run the page.

I am baffled... I have never had these issues with session handling before. Any ideas? Does it have anything to do with multiple dimensional arrays in session?

I feel like I have tried everything. I also tried so make a session_write_close() right after I change session with the right values but the result is the same.

---

### EDIT

I have come a bit closer.
I think it have something to do with the reference of $this->session.

Just before I set the session I var_dump and echo $this->session['seomthing'] this repports the value is being right - the changed value coming from class2. When I insert this value in the $_SESSION i DONT get the right value!!! I get test and not test2 that I have just been told is the value of it. There is something completely wrong with PHP here. If I set $_SESSION with a string like 'lalala' it changes. If I change the $this->session['seomthing'] right before it also works! So Session is not the issue. I can change it around.

$this->session['seomthing'] = 'sdfsdfs';

So how can vardump and echo tell me that the value is one thing but when I insert it in SESSION it is another value! This is why I was so confused. PHP tells me 2 different things.

So basically I have a variable(test) in class one. I send it to class two where I change it to test2 while I have & in font (reference). I then in class one vardump and echo it and it says it is now test2. I put it into $_SESSION and then it says value is test... and not test2... wtf?

---

### EDIT2

So I tried to make a really simple example of what I am doing. And when I do so everything works... so the answer has to be somewhere in the code... I am closing this one and digging further into this mystery.

class1.php

```
<?php
session_start();
class Class1 {

    var $session;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->session = $_SESSION['something'];
        $this->session['somethingelse'] = 'test';
        $this->main();
    }

    private function main() {
        var_dump($this->session);
        require_once 'class2.php';
        $Class2 = new Class2($this->session);

        $Class2->main();

        $this->storeSession();
    }

    private function storeSession() {
        var_dump($this->session);
        $_SESSION['something'] = $this->session;
        var_dump($_SESSION);
        echo 1;     
    }
}

new Class1();
?>
```

class2.php

```
<?php
session_start();

class class2 {

    public $session;

    function __construct(&$session) {
        $this->session = &$session;
        $this->main();
    }

    function main() {
        $this->session['somethingelse'] = 'test2';      
    }
}
?>
```

session.php

```
<?php
session_start();

var_dump(session_id());
var_dump($_SESSION);
?>
```

/RJ

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you should first call session_start(), before using $_SESSION... That could explain why your whole $_SESSION is empty.

> Remember: You must always use “session_start()” in your script if you
>   want to use the $_SESSION array. session_start() does not only start a
>   user’s session, but it continues a current session. session_start() is
>   used to get the user’s session ID and associate it with their file,
>   thus loading the variables frm the file into $_SESSION, if you do not
>   use session_start() the $_SESSION values will not be available

http://www.free2code.net/tutorials/view/php_sessions-11/page1.html

Comment: I have been programming PHP for 9 years I know where the session_start() goes ;) session_start() is in the top of all documents.

Comment: Its like I cant overwrite the session when it has first been set!

Comment: hehe, sorry - I wasn't sure you used session_start in the first document ;)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't have a session_write_close() before setting new values?

Comment: Yes I am sure. Please read the EDIT. I don't think this is a session issue but rather something completely different.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you throw away all your weird classes and stuff and experiment with a totally empty php script.

e.g. yoursite.com/test.php

Just put in the basic session stuff. session_start(), etc.

Set some session variables.

print_r($_SESSION,false); // print to screen

then, before reloading the page, delete whatever code actually sets session variables, but leave the print_r statement.

Then try loading the page like yoursite.com/test.php?anyrandomthing=whatever

See if you print the same session or not. If you do, then you've at least determined that your server is handling sessions correctly, and your problem is in your code.

Comment: Hey Buttle. I actually resolved this question. Im now sure why its not closed. As I recall the problem was found in an included stylesheet. Someone had left a background-image: url(); This made the page reload and doing some steps I wasent able to track in the beginning.